# Passing a dictionary into a SQLAlchemy select statement's where clause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

All, I'm hoping there's an easy way of doing this. I'm reading a json file which has key value pairs of a database column heading and its value. I read the json file in as a dictionary which I try to pass into a `where` clause in SQLAlchemy.

The following code returns an error:

```
with open('./customers.json') as f:
    customer_data = json.load(f)

query = sa.select([customer]).where(**customer_data)
```

```
TypeError: where() got an unexpected keyword argument 'customer_id'
```

I'm seeing I would need to pass parameters to the `where` clause like this:

```
where(sa.and_(customer.columns.customer_id == 1, customer.columns.sex == 'M')))
```

How would I be able to pass a dictionary? I imagine I'd have to get the dictionary key value pairs into this format: `table_name.columns.dict_key == dict_value`. I can't figure out how.

Comment: Would't it just be easier to use Pandas module and handle all of your data like that?

Comment: @MartínSchere, I wouldn't know how to do this in pandas, but I could look it up. I just started with this code and the lead developer has everything written with sqlalchemy and I need the results of this query in SQLAlchemy's ORM format to continue processing it.

Comment: As a little nit, you're not using the ORM, you're using the so called "core".

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks for the correction. I'll learn the finer points of all this as I work more with it. Appreciate you pointing that out.